# javascript remove a exact index character from the string

Tags: javascript

```js
let test = 'This is the test string';

console.log(test.substr(3));

console.log(test.slice(3));

console.log(test.substring(3));
```

Theese methods are removing first 3 character. But i want to remove only third character from the string.

The log has to be:  ' Ths is the test string'

İf you help me i will be glad. All examples are giving from the substr, slice eg. eg. Are there any different methods?

Comment: `test.slice(0,2) + test.slice(3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, get the first `3` chars, then add chars `4-end`, connect those to get the desired result:

```js
let test = 'This is the test string';

let res = test.substr(0, 2) + test.substr(3);

console.log(res);
```

Since `substr` uses the following parameters

> [`substr(start, length)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)
>
> **Start** The index of the first character to include in the returned substring.
>
> **Length** *Optional*. The number of characters to extract.
> *If length is omitted*, substr() extracts characters **to the end of the string**.

We can use `test.substr(3)` to get from the 3'th to the **last** char without specifying the length of the string

Answer (score 1):

```js
const test = 'This is the test string';
const result = test.slice(0, 2) + test.slice(3);
console.log(result);
```

You can achieve this by concatenating the two parts of the string, using `.slice()`.

Comment: `test.length` can be removed since `slice` has `str.length` as default end param.

Comment: No need to add 2nd parameter in your 2nd `.slice` call. By default it will slice till the end of string when no 2nd argument is provided :)

Answer (score 0):

You can  achieve it using substring method and concatenating the strings

```
 str = "Delete me ";
 function del_one_char(string , removeAt){
      return string.substring(0, removeAt) + string.substring( removeAt + 1, string.length); 
 }
  console.log(del_one_char(str , 2))
  // result one character at 2nd position is deleted
```